# Why does Google Chrome on Android has so many permissions?

Tags: security

Just found out through a connection tracking app, that Google Chrome on my Android 9 has so many permissions granted . Permissions like :-

1. Pair with Bluetooth devices
2. Access Bluetooth settings
3. Read your contacts
4. request install packages
5. Download files without notification
6. Find accounts on the device
7. Download files without notification

**Are there permissions Normal?**
When I check in the permission settings of the Chrome App, it does not show all these permissions enabled!
Have factory reset the phone too
[image: Screenshot -1]

[image: Screenshot-2]

Comment: Normal? I don't know.  Acceptable?  Definitely not.  I strongly recommend using a different browser instead of Google Chrome.

Comment: Chrome has most likely that much permissions for being able to run Progressive Web Apps (PWA). Such apps are special web sites that behave like an app. And of course such an app may needs access to Bluetooth, fingerprint authentication, push/C2D messages, create launcher shortcuts, and so on. Most of those permissions are already useful for Chrome itself, hence they are not limited to PWA apps.

Comment: Just to pick a few, the Bluetooth permission is needed for interacting with [Web Bluetooth API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API). The Contacts permission is needed for using [Contact Picker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Contact_Picker_API#browser_compatibility). Both are standard web features.

Answer (score 0):

so yes permissions:

- pair and acces bluetooth - this is STANDARD for some sites in html/html5 , if browser wouldn't have this permission some website could be broken.
- read contacts - it's a next html api and also can break some sites if disabled.
- install packages/download files - you think that you can't download things from internet? just look at clouds, github (and other similar sites), pages for converting media types, etc.
- find accounts on device - for logging in to your google account which can be use for f.e. : tabs and bookmarks

and if you think that sites doesn't require some permissions look at my game : https://hacknorris-notyetbanned.github.io/glitched.github.io/game/index.html (yes it's self-advertisement but it'd answer your question i think...)

and a few sources with these and a few similar permissions and API's for use by YOU : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_geolocation.asp ; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Contact_Picker_API ; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API ;

and if about not showing these permissions in system - it may be due to ROM on your phone.